# page-break-after with cycle for

Tags: php, css

I get information from an sql query and then I show it with a cycle for me it appears well the first hour but when I need to show more data it does not show it on the second page.

My code:

```
<div class="ax7 " style="page-break-after: always;   ">
<?php    
$num = 1;    
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($beneficiarios)); $i++) {    
$li = $beneficiarios[$i];
$usuario  = $li->Act_escala;    
$nombre = $li->Act_Nombre;    
$fecha = $li->Act_FechaInicio;    
?>
<p>
<?php echo $num . '.-' . $usuario. ' ' . $nombre ?> , a contar del
<?php echo $fecha ?> </p>
<?php    
 $num++;    
}    
?>
</div>
```

also on the first page shows me the information to the end of my sheet and I do not know how to upload it and continue to show the information on the second page from the top: 0

Answer (score 1):

I try the following :

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```